# Trvial HTTP Server library for .NET

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core

I want to add a very basic HTTP functionality to a .NET Core application. I want something similar to [Akka HTTP Server](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html).

Basically, I want something that allows me to accept a request containing a JSON array and respond with a JSON back.

Can anyone suggest a library, Nuget package or similar that I can use? I don't want ASP.NET MVC or other heavy frameworks. All tutorials that I could find are not targeted towards service to service communication.

Comment: You are talking about ASP.NET Core *Web API* projects, not MVC. All such tutorials are about service to service communications. What you ask is already available when you create a new project with `dotnet new webapi`. Check [Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and the other tutorials in that section that cover Visual Studio Code, VS for Mac etc

Comment: As for `heavy frameworks` define heavy. Do you have a specific requirement? Have you *tried* ASP.NET Core Web API and found it's too heavy or is it just an assumption? Remember that ASP.NET Core works through middleware components that you explicitly add. If you don't want something, just don't add it.

Comment: Please note that _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it_. [Help: What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is a bit _blurry_. I'm a beginner in .NET and just trying to find my way. Heavy for me is having stuff like _authentication_, _database integrations_ and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of [web server implementations in `ASP.NET Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/)

- [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel)
- [WebListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/weblistener)

or [implement your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin) (`OWIN` based).